# Showing MIN, MAX and AVE from an alias Column

Tags: mysql, sql

**My MySQL Knowledge** = Beginner

```
Columns: MonthlyIncome and MonthlyDebt
Table: customer
```

**Desired Output:** Present the MIN, MAX, and AVE of the difference of MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt. `MonthlyIncome`- `MonthlyDebt` = `NetIncome`.

**My failed attempt** from research and experiments:

1. Get the difference between the two columns and put them in an aliased column.
2. Select from the aliased column (NetIncome) to present the MIN, MAX, and AVE.

**The Failed Query:**

```
SELECT MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt AS NetIncome
FROM    (
        SELECT MIN(NetIncome) AS MinNet,
        MAX(NetIncome) AS MaxNet,
        AVE(NetIncome) AS AveNet
        FROM customers
        ) AS subqueryalias
```

The failure yields an **ERROR** of:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NetIncome' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the `NetIncome` in the outer query, but referenced it in the inner query, which is a no go. The inner query is executed first. I would not even use the alias, just use the expression in all the aggregate functions:

```
select min(MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt), max(MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt), avg(MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt)
from customers
```

Comment: Thank you @Shadow. I never thought that doing the calculation for each functions would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn our `SELECT` inside-out like

```
SELECT 
  MIN(NetIncome) AS MinNet,
  MAX(NetIncome) AS MaxNet,
  AVE(NetIncome) AS AveNet
FROM ( SELECT MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt AS NetIncome 
       FROM customers ) AS subqueryalias
```

The inner subquery `SELECT MonthlyIncome - MonthlyDebt AS NetIncome FROM customers` gets evaluated first and generates the column `NetIncome` for further use in the outer (Main) `select`.

Comment: Hi @cars10 thank you for the reply. I could not verify the solution due to access limitations `execute command denied`. I, however, still appreciate your input.